# Why did Roy immediately leave the Diwali party?

Tags: character, the-office

In S03E06 of *The Office*, Roy and Pam had already broken off the wedding and Roy had stated in a previous episode that he was trying to "win her back".

Well, right when Roy walks into the Diwali party and sees Pam dancing he walks out...

**Why did Roy immediately decide to leave?**

Comment: My interpretation has been that when he sees her dancing he realizes how different she is since they broke up and how happy and independent she is and this makes him feel insecure and unsure of himself so he leaves because he doesn't want to hold her back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Roy was trying to win Pam back as he understood he took her for granted before as he once said in S03E01

> Roy: After Pam dumped me, I um, I kinda stopped taking care of myself
>   there, and uh, I hit bottom when uh, drunk driving arrest. I've been
>   working out and um, you know, I'm not gonna take her for granted. I
>   gotta win her back.

This shows he was clearly hurt. But while he wanted to win her badly, seeing Pam dancing and later talking to another man at Diwali, Roy probably got more upset and decided to leave rather then stay and talk to Her. He saw Pam is clearly less worried  about their breakup and seems much happier, he couldn't watch that.
He could have stayed for the sake of Pam but I think sure Roy was trying to win her but as he by nature is not very caring or affectionate , he could not try and get Pam to like him.